# Admin Bar doesn't show up

Tags: wordpress

The admin bar doesn't show! I looked around and did everything I found:

1. Shut down all plugins - doesn't work.
2. Changed do default theme - shows (so it's a theme problem)
3. Checked if I have the `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` - doesn't work
4. Changed the `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` - doesn't show any error
5. Re-uploaded all the wordpress `wp-admin` and `wp-includes` files - doesn't work
6. Disabled the css on site - still not seen

Any other suggestions?

Comment: can you share the live site.

Comment: here:
http://www.dogslife.org.il/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added the

```
wp_head();
```

`header.php` in theme editor right before `</head>`

and `wp_footer();` right before `</body>`

Comment: yes i put the wp_head(); right before </head>. but the wp_footer(); should be right before what ?..

Comment: Please check the view source from firefox. Is there any error showing ?

Comment: i have some errors coming from plugins (but when i shout them off it's still dosn't show). and some others from the theme but it dosn't seem related.

Comment: The wp_footer is not is proper place. Please take a look at the view source from firefox browser then you can make sense.